# EF Core 'Entity type does not have a discriminator property configured'

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have a Model structure like this

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public abstract class AbstractRegistration : BaseEntity
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
public class Registration1 : AbstractRegistration
{
    public string ReferenceNumber { get; set; }
}
public class Registration2 : AbstractRegistration
{
}
```

Config section is

```
public class AbstractRegistrationConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AbstractRegistration>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AbstractRegistration> builder)
    {
        // map table and schema
        builder.ToTable("tbl_reg");

        // map properties with actual columns
        builder.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("id");
        builder.Property(t => t.UserId).HasColumnName("userId");

        builder.HasDiscriminator<int>("Id")
                .HasValue<AbstractRegistration>(0)
                .HasValue<Registration1>(1)
                .HasValue<Registration2>(2);
        builder.HasDiscriminator<string>("RegNumber")
                .HasValue<Registration1>("1");
    }
}

public class Registration1Config : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Registration1>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Registration1> builder)
    {
        // map table and schema
        builder.ToTable("tbl_reg1");

        // map properties with actual columns
        builder.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("id");
        builder.Property(t => t.RegNumber).HasColumnName("reg_num");
    }
}
```

The error coming is 'The entity type 'Registration1' is part of a hierarchy, but does not have a discriminator property configured.'

Please suggest

EntityFrameworkCore Version=2.0.1.0

Comment: Take a look at [Table Per Hierarchy Inheritance](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/inheritance/table-per-hierarchy) and see if that helps.

Comment: @MarkG the approach you mentioned is different, my base class is related to 1 table and derived is related to other so i need to include config for both.

Comment: Looks to me like you're configuring multiple discriminators for the same entity and you're not comple

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is a design problem. You've defined the discriminator on the "Id" property, which is also the key of your base entity. Consider using a different property as a discriminator, like "RegistrationType."

Secondly, it's not advisable to use an existing column as a discriminator directly. In Entity Framework Core, drop the existing column and recreate it as a discriminator, as you've attempted in your code. However, ensure that the discriminator property is not the key column.

Thirdly, if you're using this property in .NET Entity, mark it as [NotMapped] to prevent it from being persisted to the database.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AbstractRegistration : BaseEntity
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string RegistrationType { get; set; } // Use this as discriminator
}

public class Registration1 : AbstractRegistration
{
    public string ReferenceNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Registration2 : AbstractRegistration
{
}

public class AbstractRegistrationConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AbstractRegistration>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AbstractRegistration> builder)
    {
        // map table and schema
        builder.ToTable("tbl_reg");

        // map properties with actual columns
        builder.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("id");
        builder.Property(t => t.UserId).HasColumnName("userId");

        builder.HasDiscriminator<string>("RegistrationType")
                .HasValue<AbstractRegistration>("0")
                .HasValue<Registration1>("1")
                .HasValue<Registration2>("2");
    }
}

public class Registration1Config : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Registration1>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Registration1> builder)
    {
        // map table and schema
        builder.ToTable("tbl_reg1");

        // map properties with actual columns
        builder.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("id");
        builder.Property(t => t.ReferenceNumber).HasColumnName("reg_num");
    }
}
```