# EF6 Use Existing Db Column as Discriminator

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, tph

I am using Entity Framework 6 Code First for my project.
Entities have Inheritance so I am following TPH(Table per Hierarchy).
I read following [Article](http://%20https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) and many others.

None of them explain a way in which I can use an existing DB Column mapped to a property in Base Entity as Discriminator.

Based on the sample below I get following Exception

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> > TaskType: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'TaskType' is already defined.

I think EF's auto generated Discriminator and my Entities Mapping is Conflicting.

Is there a possible way to instruct EF to not auto generate column and use Entity mapped Column.
If not, is there any explanation of this can not be avoided.

Peace.

I have Entities in following format

```
public enum TaskType
{
    Random = 0,
    Polished = 1,
    Dropping = 2
}

public interface ITask
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    TaskType typeofTask { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseTask : ITask
{
    public BaseTask(string name, TaskType type)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.typeofTask = type;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TaskType typeofTask { get; set; }
}

public class RandomTask : BaseTask
{
    public RandomTask() : base("My Random", TaskType.Random)
    {
    }
    public int Owner { get; set; }
}

public class PolishedTask : BaseTask
{
    public PolishedTask() : base("My Polished", TaskType.Polished)
    {

    }
}

public class DBContextTest : DbContext
{
    public DBContextTest(string connection) : base(connection)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<BaseTask> Task { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BaseTask>().Map<RandomTask>(m => m.Requires("TaskType").HasValue(1))
           .Map<PolishedTask>(m => m.Requires("TaskType").HasValue(1));

        modelBuilder.Entity<BaseTask>().Property(p => p.typeofTask).HasColumnName("TaskType");
    }

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            DBContextTest dataContext = new DBContextTest("Server = (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;DataBase = LOC2;Trusted_Connection = True;");
            RandomTask randomtask = new RandomTask();
            PolishedTask polishedTask = new PolishedTask();
            dataContext.Task.Add(randomtask);
            dataContext.Task.Add(polishedTask);
            dataContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The discriminator column may not be part of the entity afaik. It may be you can somehow code around it, but that could be a rather big task.

Comment: please refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/77486061/5697591

Answer (score 1):

Remove TaskType from your entity and let EF manage that as part of the TPH mapping. To differentiate types if you're dealing with a base-class collection, use `.OfType<PolishedTask>()` rather than `.Where(x => x.TaskType == TaskType.Polished)`  EF should take care of the rest. If you do want it on the entity, create a non-mapped property in your sub-classes.
I.e.

```
public abstract class BaseTask
{
  [NotMapped]
  public abstract TaskType TaskType { get; }
}

public class PolishedTask
{
  [NotMapped]
  public override TaskType TaskType => TaskType.Polished

  // or
  //public override TaskType TaskType
  //{
  //  get { return TaskType.Polished; }
  //}
}
```